# Debian 8 Live Bootable USB isn't persistent

Tags: linux, debian, persistent

So I would like to install Debian 8 live on my USB so I can do my programming and such on it.

Well, I got a live version running, and in fact I am typing on Debian right now.

Problem is, it's not persistent, and there isn't an option when you first boot it up to select it.

I have access to Windows 10 and Debian, although I will have to wait around 45minutes until I can use Debian.

Also, as a side note, lxds would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Stick with [LinuxLiveUSB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) where you can enable the persistent option. Or you could create a Folder on your Stick to save all files in there.

A slow USB Port causes basically the long loading time so you may try to use a USB 3.0 Port and Stick.

Answer (score 1):

Download the debian image from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current-live/) :

e,g:

```
wget http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/release/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-8.6.0-amd64-cinnamon-desktop.iso
```

Make your usb bootable:

```
dd if=debian-live-8.6.0-amd64-cinnamon-desktop.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

unmount your USB then run Gparted , select your USB , right click on the `unallocated` partition and select new , create the new partition as follow :

```
Create as: Primary partition
File System: ext2 
label: live-rw
```

Apply changes and boot from USB with persistence .